# Real Google static map URL limit

Tags: google-maps-static-api

One of the features on my site is a landing page that uses static maps to show a route created by the user. I noted some time ago that some routes would break, and presumed that this was due to very long routes exceeding the 2048 character limit. It's a pretty simple fix; I make the routes shorter by pulling out every other point (as many times as it takes to get the URL short enough.) Since these are very long routes and relatively small images, the loss of precision isn't really noticeable.

Here's the thing though. I went back to find some older very long routes to test with before deploying, and I couldn't find any that were broken. I'm finding routes with URLs over 6000 characters that are working just fine: http://gmap-pedometer.com/gp/bookmark/view/id/6829704.

In fact, I can't find any routes that are breaking. There must have been a change on the API side. The documentation still says the URL limit is 2048. Does anyone know what the new limit is?

Comment: Are you testing in the same browser (IE) as when you had issues?  (Was the issue definitely on the Google Map side and not the browser truncating the URL)?

Comment: Good point, I honestly don't have valid info on what browsers I would have seen this on before. But I haven't used IE myself in many years, and I've tested in chrome (Mac), Firefox (Mac), and Twitter client on iOS. I'll check the Windows side through browserstack in a few minutes when I reach my desk. Fact remains though, API docs don't seem to match reality and I'd like to know the real limit.

Comment: Just tried in IE10 and Chrome on Win7 and same results. Definitely seems like something in the API changed.

Comment: OK, just a guess.  No clue on that and good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#url-size-restriction) is already updated:

> Google Static Maps API URLs are restricted to 8192 characters in size.

Comment: Aha, so it has. Guess they were listening!

Answer (score 0):

They should provide a POST API to get a static map with the really long encoded path,
In my case, when I drew some driving convex hull polygon, the static get API reach its limitation.